# R- Non-informative vs Informative Prior for Bayesian Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic, bayesian, prior

I'm kinda new to  Bayesian Statistics and I'd like to try to fit Bayesian Logistic Regression but I don't have prior knowledge about my dataset. So, I guess I have to use non-informative prior for fitting the model, correct? If so, what would be considered to be a non-informative prior distribution for logistic regression and also what would be considered to be informative prior distribution? If you could also point to more useful resources, that will be appreciated.

Comment: In principle, you can use non-informative prior, but for fitting model in some software packages, a vague prior should be given. You should write down the model and the parameter that you want to give prior, so that one can gives suggestions.

Comment: i think you can find suggestions fro priors on the stan site.https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations. try to express what a change in each coeffiecient means for logistic regression. eg a 1 unit change in x has y-fold increase in odds...

Comment: It's never the case that you don't know anything about an effect.  For example if dealing with a treatment that is not a cure we know that the odds ratio is not zero and very seldom see odds ratios < 0.1.  You can capture that by using a normal prior for the log odds ratio, computing $\sigma$ so that P(OR < 0.1) = 0.01 for example.

Comment: See [this paper by A Gelman](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/priors11.pdf)